# tastypie queryset values is not being displayed

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have this tastypie resource:

```
class TagResource_min(ModelResource):
     class Meta:
          queryset=Question.objects.values('text', 'id')
```

When I do this I have the error:

```
{

    "error_message": "'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'",
    "traceback": "
        Traceback (most recent call last): 

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 219, in wrapper    
        response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 450, in dispatch_list    
        return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 482, in dispatch    
        response = method(request, **kwargs)  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1340, in get_list    
        for obj in to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name]  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1340, in <listcomp>    
        for obj in to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name]  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 895, in full_dehydrate    
        data[field_name] = method(bundle)  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1068, in dehydrate_resource_uri    
        return self.get_resource_uri(bundle)  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 819, in get_resource_uri    
        return self._build_reverse_url(url_name, kwargs=self.resource_uri_kwargs(bundle_or_obj))  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 798, in resource_uri_kwargs    
        kwargs.update(self.detail_uri_kwargs(bundle_or_obj))  

        File \"/home/will/agora/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 775, in detail_uri_kwargs    
        kwargs[self._meta.detail_uri_name] = getattr(bundle_or_obj, self._meta.detail_uri_name)

        AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'"

}
```

The `'dict'` it is referring to must be the queryset obtained by `Question.objects.values('text', 'id')`. When I log into shell and ask for `Question.objects.values('text', 'id')` I have the following:

```
<QuerySet [{'text': 'Why does capillary action take place?', 'id': 1}, {'text': "If a human brain was connected to a fish's body, how would the humans thoughts change?", 'id': 2},...
```

What am I doing wrong by using `objects.values()`? How do I display a new queryset using `objects.values()`?

**EDIT** When I use the `Question.objects.values()` it returns an array of `dict` which does not have the attribute `dict.pk`. But when I do `Question.objects.all()` it returns an array of `ModelResource` type, which all return an integer when I call `ModelResource.pk`.

This information is not really helpful... haha. Because I am sure that the solution lies in the tastypie or django library. Althought, if I can figure out a way to attach a pk on the dict that will solve my problems.

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace?

Comment: I updated it with the trace back. And added a comment.

Comment: Thank you @Evans for fixing the traceback, and adding in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `values()` method returns a queryset that returns dictionaries instead of model instances. A model instance has a `pk` attribute but the dictionary does not. Tastypie is trying to access `pk` in the dict, thus giving the error. You need to use a method that returns a queryset giving model instances.

From [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) use `values()`:

> when you know you’re only going to need values from a small number of the available fields and you won’t need the functionality of a model instance object.

In your case, you do need the functionality of model instance object, `pk` attribute.

I'd suggest using `Question.objects.all()`

Comment: Thank you, although this is part of a greater problem. I do not need to use the values() function but I do need some way of changing the `queryset` to a set of tags rather than questions.

Comment: Using values is a solution to my greater problem referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325395/finding-most-popular-tag-taggit-tastypie-django

Comment: Although, upon reflection it seems as though I am going about this all wrong. You referenced django's documentation saying that, "when you know you’re only going to need values from a small number." Well I both need the functionality of a model and this will be for a large number of available fields. Seems as though your answer is correct.