# Finding most popular tag Taggit Tastypie Django

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-taggit

### Context

I have been having conflict. Currenly, I am creating a question answer application. Each question has a tag, and I want to show the most popular tags (e.g. tags that have the most questions associated with it).

### Specifics

I am using `django-taggit`'s `TaggableManager` to do so. Here is the model definition of the `Question`:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
```

So now I have the several tags attached to questions.

## Question

How do I make a tastypie resource to display the tags **and** sort them by which tag has the most questions associated with it?

### My attempts

I have really only had one decently successful attempt at making this work. Here is the tastypie resource:

```
class TagResource_min(ModelResource):
     def dehydrate(self, bundle):
          bundle.data['total_questions'] len(Question.objects.filter(tags__slug=bundle.obj.slug))
          return bundle  
     class Meta:
          queryset=Tag.objects.all()
```

Returns a nice JSON with a variable called `total_questions` with the number of questions associated with it. Although, dehydrate is after the `sort_by` part of the request cycle specified [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#flow-through-the-request-response-cycle), so I cannot sort the resource by `total_questions`. Here is the JSON:

```
{

    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 13
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "testing tag",
            "resource_uri": "/full/tag/1/",
            "slug": "testing-tag",
            "total_questions": 2
        },
        ...]
}
```

Another attempt I had went a different way trying to make the `queryset` be formed from the `Question` model:

```
 queryset=Question.objects.filter(~Q(tags__slug=None)).values('tags', 'tags__slug').annotate(total_questions=Count(Tag))
```

The problem with this was that the `filter` function turns the result to `dict` type instead of `models.Model` type. The key difference was that `models.Model` has the attribute `pk` which is a type of identification, and the `dict` does not have that.

Any contribution is much appriciated! Thank you!

Comment: It seems as though counting up all the tags is hard to do, if anyone has any alternative way of counting tags that is not even using `taggit` I would love to hear it or see a reference.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking for the same.